# in my content page of html, division is moving downwards

Tags: jquery, html, css

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #1874F1;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796";
}
div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 90%;
}
div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}
#content2 {
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 70%;
    margin-top: -245px;
    height: 100px;
}
#content2.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
#table table,
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #1874F1;
    text-align: left;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
th {
    background-color: #1874F1;
}
th,
td {
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1874F1;
}
tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content1">
        <h2><font color="#1874F1">Custom Web
        Development</font></h2><button class="accordion">What Bluepetal
        Does?</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <br>
            <p><font color="black" size="3">Bluepetal has a reputation for
            creating innovative custom web applications that meet and exceed
            expectations. Our specialized custom web application development
            engineers offer the highest level of usability, scalability and
            complete compatibility in browsers and platforms. Each of our
            modules is designed to fit into a framework that is mindful of
            usability, performance, security and auditing. Since every company
            is unique with its own specific needs, we invest a considerable
            amount of time trying to learn how the business works so we can
            propose unique and innovative options for the clients.</font></p>
        </div><button class="accordion">Web application</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <br>
            <p><font color="black" size="3">There are three main parts as to
            what custom web application development is all about. It’s the
            planning, the creation and the maintaining of web-based software.
            Custom data applications as the most popular type of application we
            create, these include business processes automation, Customer
            relationship management system, custom ecommerce software and one
            of a kind applications build for a specific purpose. Every custom
            application is expected to integrate with other softwares so as to
            avoid double entry and make the process efficient, we work with
            most book keeping and ERP systems including Quickbooks, Sage,
            Navision and Microsoft Great Plains.</font></p>
        </div><button class="accordion">Services</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <br>
            <p><font color="black" size="3">All our web applications are
            responsive to support cell phones and tablets natively, our testing
            team evaluates usability on physical mobile devices to ensure our
            systems can be effectively used in any environment.(Pulse possesses
            a library of over 2000 modules built by inhouse engineers, these
            including PDF manipulation, media manipulation, social networking,
            integration with ERP systems like SAP, mainframe plugins, office
            automation systems like Visual)</font></p>
        </div>
        <script>
                    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++)
                    {
                        acc[i].onclick = function()
                        {
                            this.classList.toggle("active");
                            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                        }
                    }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><font color="white">Other Web Development
                Services</font></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="ad.html"><span><img src=
                    "images/appdev1.png"></span>Application development</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="epd.html"><span><img src="images/ent.png"></span>
                    Enterprise portal development</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="ecs.html"><span><img src=
                    "images/E-Commerce-Icon.png"></span> Ecommerce
                    solutions-B2B/B2C</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="fasm.html"><span><img src="images/fb.png"></span>
                    Facebook apps & Social media</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="ecw.html"><span><img src=
                    "images/e_c.png"></span>Ecommerce websites</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpy13.jpg)
final view of content is absolutely fine.

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaskW.jpg) 
while I click accordion in first division, the right division of table is moving downwards.i want to keep the table at a fixed position.

while i click other accordion still right division is moving downwards.
please suggest me how to keep the table fixed

Comment: Please provide the code, ideally with a jsfiddle which reproduces the problem and (optionally) the "1st image" you're mentioning.

Comment: Try changing the order of your contents, so that your #content2 is above your #content1.
Then try to experiment with position: absolute for your #content2.

Comment: And you really shouldn't use things like margin-top: -245px. In general you shouldn't use margin to position your element.

Comment: Thank you @RicoOcepek . got the solution. u r absolutely correct

Comment: @Anuroop.k Please don't forget to upvote an accept my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of your contents, so that your `#content2` is above your `#content1`. Then try to experiment with position: absolute for your `#content2`.

And you really shouldn't use things like `margin-top: -245px`. In general you shouldn't use margin to position your element.